# Can't connect to the default server of pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have just installed the pgAdmin-4, and trying to connect to the default server installed with it (PostgreSQL 9.5). It asks for the password (Which I assume by default it's "postgres"), however, I keep receiving the following message:

`could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

I am working on Windows 7.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to remove `pgadmin` from the problem. Try to connect with the command line using `psql` - if you get the same message you know that the problem is not with pgadmin. If the problem continues with psql then probably your configuration of postgresql is not complete. The issue might be in the file [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) - this file controls who is allowed to connect to the backend. You might also check that the server application is running, using an appropriate Windows utility.